# In elisp, search and replace only on lines containing a specific string

Tags: search, replace

Running spacemacs 0.200.13 on emacs 25.2.2 on Kubuntu 18.04.

I need to search and replace only on lines containing a specific string.

Interactively, I use `occur`, move to the `occur` buffer, and do all search and replacement there.

I would, now, like to do the same in Elisp code. So, I wrote the following code:

```el
(defun xx-things ()
  (interactive)
  (save-excursion
    (goto-char (point-min))
    (while (search-forward "A" nil t)
      (while (search-forward "B" nil t)
        (replace-match "C" 1)))))
```

And used it on a buffer with:

```
AB
BB
CB
```

But it replaces all Bs with Cs whereas it should only replace AB with AC.

What is wrong here? How do I set it right?

Comment: When searching for `B` you must set the `BOUND` argument of `search-forward` to `(line-end-position) `. Depending on what you want you also could also add `(forward-line 0)` after `(search-forward "A" nil t)` to start the search for `B` **at the beginning of the line** containing `A`. Post an answer when you have a working version and accept it.

Comment: @Tobias I am awfully sorry I need to ask something as basic as this. But I am not able to set the `bound` or `limit` for my `search-forward`. I tried `(while (search-forward "A" (line-end-position nil) nil t)` but that does not work. Tried googling for setting the limit/ bound, but no luck. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You must not just add `(line-end-position)` but replace the `nil` with `(line-end-position)`. Currently your argument list looks like: `STRING="A", BOUND=(line-end-position nil), NOERROR=nil, COUNT=t`. Two problems: `NOERROR` should be `t` and `COUNT` must be `nil` or a number, it must not be `t`.

Comment: @Tobias A BiG thank you for your help. But looks like I am not able to fathom what's happening. I have updated the code. Now it hangs --- looks like it goes in some kind of infinite loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After you showed some effort for solving the problem I post here a version that is working for me. (At first I did not present you a full solution to give you the chance to learn from your own problems.)

The main problem with your code is that you do not restrict the search for `B` to the line where you found `A`.

EDIT: User @deshmukh found out that `search-forward`only goes to the end boundary in the case of no matches if the argument `NOERROR` is not nil and not t. Therefore `t` has to be replaced by 0 in the search for `"B"`.

```el
(defun xx-things ()
  (interactive)
  (save-excursion
    (goto-char (point-min))
    (while (search-forward "A" nil t)
      (beginning-of-line)
      (while (search-forward "B" (line-end-position) 0)
        (replace-match "C" 1)))))
```

Tested with emacs 26.1. But that code should run quite independently of the `emacs-version`.

Comment: I had reached exactly here. But it hangs. After I interrupt with a `C-g`, I see that only the first instance of AB is converted to AC.

Comment: @deshmukh Try to debug with edebug: Put point at `defun` and press `C-u M-C-x`. Afterwards use `M-x xx-things`.

Comment: Thanks, yet again. I could find out the error. In the code, if it finds a line with A but not with B, it just keeps going back and forth on the same line. So, I changed the line to `(while (search-forward "B" (line-end-position) 0)` and now it works. BTW, that 0 was because the documentation said not nil and not t! And now it works. :)

Comment: @deshmukh I've corrected the solution. Thanks for the notice.